# CSS Looks Great in FF and Chrome but not in IE8

Tags: css

Yes another question that is a little Unique because I cant find the same question anywhere.  I am trying to make a website and so far it looks great in FF and Chrome but in IE8 it looks like crap.  I dont know how to fix it been looking up others to see if they are like mine but are not. 
the site is funspot.zxq.net yeah I will be changing that up too that is just my start but this is the code

```
    <html>
<head>
 <title>The Fun Spot </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">

<div id="header">

</div>

<div id="horizontalnav">
   <div class="navlinks ">
        <ul>
        <li><a href="http://www.Facebook.com" target="_blank">Facebook</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.gaiaonline.com" target="_blank">Gaia</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.roblox.com" target="_blank">Roblox</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.adventurequest.com" target="_blank">Adventure Quest</a>        </li> 
        <li><a href="http://www.animefreak.tv" target="_blank">Anime Freak</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.youtube.com" target="_blank">Youtube</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="leftnav">
    <p>Info: Love the Knicks as you can see so when I post some stuff here about this. This site would be about me and get better as I become a better developer. </p>
</div>


<div id="theMeat" >
    <p><img src="AmareStoudemireNY.jpg" alt="Amare Stoudemire" > This is my favorite Knicks Player right now.  Even though Carmelo Anthony is awesome, Stoudemire started the road to the playoffs not really 100% by himself but by himself.  </p>

    <p> <img src="ewing_knicks.jpg" alt="Patrick Ewing" > This is the man and my favorite player of all times! He was great and I wish that they never traded him his final year because that was an a injustice.  He gave them all he ever had and they dissed him, if you agree send me a email. <a href="mailto:daddycardona@gmail.com">Daddy</a></p>

    <p><img src="favoriteKnicksTeam.jpg" alt="1994 Team" > Now this here is the team you dont forget about.  I think the Knicks put together alot of awesome teams but this one was my Favorite.  The starters were Patrick Ewing, Anthony Mason, Derek Harper, John Starks, and Charles Oakley. Oh and Pat Riley as the coach. Yeah baby.</p>

</div>

<div id="rightnav">

    <p>There will be site's that helped me create this site OOH Rah </p>

</div>

<div id="footer">
<p align="center">Date Edited 20110408</p>
</div>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and for the CSS

```
#container  {
width: 100%;
}

#header{
width: 89%;
height: 15%;
position: relative;
background-image: url(Header.jpg);
border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;

}

#horizontalnav  {
width: 89%;
height: 30px;
position: relative;
background-color: #00008B;
border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
}
.navlinks  {
position: absolute; top: 4px; left:240px; 
}
.navlinks ul { 
margin: auto;
}
.navlinks li {
margin: 0px 18px 0px 0px;
list-style-type: none;
display: inline;
}
.navlinks li a {
color: #FF8C00;
padding: 5px 12px 7px;
text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-family: Courier New;
}
 .navlinks li a:hover{
 color: #ffffff;
 text-decoration: underline;
} 
#header p  {
color: #000000;
font-family: Courier New;
font-weight: bold;
}
#leftnav {
float: left;
width: 10%;
height: 70%;
background-color: #00008B;
border-right: 1px dashed #694717;
}
#leftnav p{
 color : #FF8C00 ;
font-family : Courier New ;
font-size : 16px ;
}       

#rightnav  {
float: left;
width: 9.9%;
height: 70%;
background-color: #00008B;
border-left: 1px dashed #694717;
}
#rightnav p{
color : #FF8C00 ;
font-family : Courier New ;
font-size : 16px ;
 }
#theMeat  {
 background-color: #FF8C00 ;
 overflow : auto ;
 float: left;
 width : 68.9% ;
 height : 70% ;
 padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
 }
#theMeat p {
color : #00008B ;
font-family : Courier New ;
font-size : 16px ;
}

#footer  {
clear: both;
 background-color: #00008B;
width : 88.9% ;
}
#footer p{
color : #FF8C00 ;
font-family : Courier New ;
font-size : 16px ;
}
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but you haven't told us what isn't working. Just given us code.  Describe what issue you are having. I'm guessing adding margin:0 auto; to a few divs will fix it... but still, describe the problem, just not give us code.

Comment: Sorry Yes its the actual site if you look at it on IE and then on Chrome or fire fox the whole layout is not working in IE

Comment: How about a screenshot or two?

Comment: not many people here will paste your code into an html file and look at it in 2 browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I fixed how it looks in ie8. I change the height from percentage to pixels and it worked.
If that works for you, use it.

here is how it looks https://i.stack.imgur.com/en1P0.png [image]

The HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"> 

<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>The Fun Spot</TITLE>
<META content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" http-equiv=Content-Type><LINK 
rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="/style.css">
<META name=GENERATOR content="MSHTML 8.00.6001.19019"></HEAD>
<BODY>
<DIV id=container>
<DIV id=header></DIV>
<DIV id=horizontalnav>
<DIV class="navlinks ">
<UL>
  <LI><A href="http://www.facebook.com/" target=_blank>Facebook</A> 
  <LI><A href="http://www.gaiaonline.com/" target=_blank>Gaia</A> 
  <LI><A href="http://www.roblox.com/" target=_blank>Roblox</A> 
  <LI><A href="http://www.adventurequest.com/" target=_blank>Adventure Quest</A> 

  <LI><A href="http://www.animefreak.tv/" target=_blank>Anime Freak</A> 
  <LI><A href="http://www.youtube.com/" target=_blank>Youtube</A> 
</LI></UL></DIV></DIV>
<DIV id=leftnav>
<P>Info: Love the Knicks as you can see so when I post some stuff here about 
this. This site would be about me and get better as I become a better developer. 
</P></DIV>
<DIV id=theMeat>
<P><IMG alt="Amare Stoudemire" src="stack_files/AmareStoudemireNY.jpg"> This is 
my favorite Knicks Player right now. Even though Carmelo Anthony is awesome, 
Stoudemire started the road to the playoffs not really 100% by himself but by 
himself. </P>
<P><IMG alt="Patrick Ewing" src="stack_files/ewing_knicks.jpg"> This is the man 
and my favorite player of all times! He was great and I wish that they never 
traded him his final year because that was an a injustice. He gave them all he 
ever had and they dissed him, if you agree send me a email. <A 
href="mailto:daddycardona@gmail.com">Daddy</A></P>
<P><IMG alt="1994 Team" src="stack_files/favoriteKnicksTeam.jpg"> Now this here 
is the team you dont forget about. I think the Knicks put together alot of 
awesome teams but this one was my Favorite. The starters were Patrick Ewing, 
Anthony Mason, Derek Harper, John Starks, and Charles Oakley. Oh and Pat Riley 
as the coach. Yeah baby.</P></DIV>
<DIV id=rightnav>
<P>There will be site's that helped me create this site OOH Rah </P></DIV>
<DIV id=footer>
<P align=center>Date Edited 20110408</P></DIV></DIV></BODY></HTML>
```

THE CSS

```
    #container {
    WIDTH: 100%
}
#header {
    BACKGROUND-IMAGE: url(http://funspot.zxq.net/Header.jpg); BORDER-BOTTOM: #000000 2px solid; POSITION: relative; WIDTH: 89%; HEIGHT: 100px;}
#horizontalnav {
    BORDER-BOTTOM: #000000 2px solid; POSITION: relative; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #00008b; WIDTH: 89%; HEIGHT: 30px
}
.navlinks {
    POSITION: absolute; TOP: 4px; LEFT: 240px
}
.navlinks UL {
    MARGIN: auto
}
.navlinks LI {
    LIST-STYLE-TYPE: none; MARGIN: 0px 18px 0px 0px; DISPLAY: inline
}
.navlinks LI A {
    PADDING-BOTTOM: 7px; PADDING-LEFT: 12px; PADDING-RIGHT: 12px; FONT-FAMILY: Courier New; COLOR: #ff8c00; FONT-SIZE: 16px; TEXT-DECORATION: none; PADDING-TOP: 5px
}
.navlinks LI A:hover {
    COLOR: #ffffff; TEXT-DECORATION: underline
}
#header P {
    FONT-FAMILY: Courier New; COLOR: #000000; FONT-WEIGHT: bold
}
#leftnav {
    BACKGROUND-COLOR: #00008b; WIDTH: 10%; FLOAT: left; HEIGHT: 400px; BORDER-RIGHT: #694717 1px dashed
}
#leftnav P {
    FONT-FAMILY: Courier New; COLOR: #ff8c00; FONT-SIZE: 16px
}
#rightnav {
    BORDER-LEFT: #694717 1px dashed; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #00008b; WIDTH: 9.9%; FLOAT: left; HEIGHT: 400px;
}
#rightnav P {
    FONT-FAMILY: Courier New; COLOR: #ff8c00; FONT-SIZE: 16px
}
#theMeat {
    PADDING-BOTTOM: 0px; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #ff8c00; PADDING-LEFT: 0px; WIDTH: 68.9%; PADDING-RIGHT: 0px; FLOAT: left; HEIGHT: 400px; OVERFLOW: auto; PADDING-TOP: 0px
}
#theMeat P {
    FONT-FAMILY: Courier New; COLOR: #00008b; FONT-SIZE: 16px
}
#footer {
    BACKGROUND-COLOR: #00008b; WIDTH: 88.9%; CLEAR: both
}
#footer P {
    FONT-FAMILY: Courier New; COLOR: #ff8c00; FONT-SIZE: 16px
}
```

Comment: Man thats awesome I just wonder how come it don't work with percent signs thank you. but you also added meta tags how did that work in this situation?

Comment: percents are kinda tough to use some times if you don't do it right. Pixels are much more desired. Also be sure to include the long <doctype code> in the future as IE =<8 relies heavily on it. the meta tags i think IE put it, not me. good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You are in quirks mode and IE won't attempt to perform like the other far more modern browsers. Add this to your first line: `<!doctype html>`. Then see where we stand.

Comment: I just did this as a test myself. The pages seem to render the same once there's a proper doctype in place, but it seems to "break" the page in Chrome more than it helps in IE. Methinks OP has bigger problems than he realizes.

Comment: @daddy It didn't make them look bad, it made them look *correct*. Your problem is that your code was relying on quirks rather than being founded on good design.

Comment: I am a little confused I put the doctype and it made the header and navlink bar fused with out it it looked just like how i wanted it

Comment: TO anyone how would upload snapshots so you can see the difference I am talking about.